# How to keep all values from a dataframe except where NaN is present in another dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

I am new to Pandas and I am stuck at this specific problem where I have 2 DataFrames in Pandas, e.g.

```
>>> df1
      A   B
0     1   9
1     2   6
2     3   11
3     4   8

>>> df2
      A   B
0     Nan   0.05
1     Nan   0.05
2     0.16   Nan
3     0.16   Nan
```

What I am trying to achieve is to retain all values from df1 except where there is a `NaN` in df2 i.e.

```
>>> df3
      A     B
0     Nan   9
1     Nan   6
2     3   Nan
3     4   Nan
```

I am talking about dfs with 10,000 rows each so I can't do this manually. Also indices and columns are the exact same in each case. I also have no NaN values in df1.
As far as I understand `df.update()` will either overwrite all values including `NaN` or update only those that are `NaN`.

Comment: Please use `df.to_dict()` and post the output here so we can reproduce your df

Comment: @Luke You can [`pd.read_clipboard`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html) after copying the df from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *boolean masking* using [`DataFrame.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html).

```
# df2 = df2.astype(float) # This needed if your dtypes are not floats.
m = df2.notna()
df1[m]
     A    B
0  NaN  9.0
1  NaN  6.0
2  3.0  NaN
3  4.0  NaN
```